# Using Grails + PostgreSQL - How do i debug the GORM?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am having an issue with PostgreSQL, while using Grails/GORM.  I want to be able to figure out what the query is that is running.  It is failing asking about a field that I do not have in the class, and I can not find in the db either, so I am wondering how to debug this.

Here is my exception:

> ERROR: column this_.level_version does not exist   Position: 123.
>   Stacktrace follows: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column
>   this_.level_version does not exist   Position: 123    at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
>     at grails.orm.PagedResultList.(PagedResultList.java:55)   at
>   at.TriviaController.list(script13759817432761717501241.groovy:15)     at
>   grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:186)
>     at
>   grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
>     at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:69)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `logSql=true` in your Datasource.groovy.  [See docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource).

Comment: That helped me find this: http://grails-dev.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-grails.html

Comment: If you want to see it formatted add format_sql=true in hibernate block too.