# Get last updated record in Grails

Tags: grails, hql

Is there a way to get last and recently updated records from the database?

The records don't have any date information and I don't wan't to change the table structure.
The ID also can't be used because these are edited records and not newly added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to add the field `lastUpdateted` in Domain classes
then use the method beforeUpdate from GORM, and then query using `order by lastUpdated` with limit.

See also "[How do you do a limit query in HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql)"

Answer (score 0):

clarify question!!! there are a lot of ways to do it:

- Sql logs ( like post [Using Grails + PostgreSQL - How do i debug the GORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133530/using-grails-postgresql-how-do-i-debug-the-gorm)),
- add the field **lastUpdateted** in Domain classes
- use the method **beforeUpdate** from GORM
- add Your Code in Controllers or Service, that will observe
- use filter e.t.c